# Vim latex suite "alt" macro not working

Tags: editors, vim

I tried using the alt+i macro to insert list item intelligently, but it didn't work and neither did other alt macros for latex suite. Any insight to resolve this problem is very well appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you seen the note on the usage of `: set winaltkeys=no` in [§3.10 of the documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/altkey-mappings.html)?

Comment: Thanks! That didn't work, but that document you linked did help me make another macro that trigger the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the way that some terminals expect the alt key combinations differ. Some send "8-bit" codes and some send "7-bit" codes. I haven't invested the time to fully understand this issue. But, I have fixed this problem, myself, by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim) solution posted on StackOverflow. Thus, I have added the following my .vimrc:

```
   let c='a'
   while c <= 'z'
     exec "set <A-".c.">=\e".c
     exec "imap \e".c." <A-".c.">"
     let c = nr2char(1+char2nr(c))
   endw
   set timeout ttimeoutlen=50
```